# 0 function loaded error in Azure app service custom docker container

Tags: azure-functions, azure-web-app-service

Azure function image runs successfully on local PC (1 function loaded). After deploying to App Service, the container runs but has error log: 0 function loaded......

Answer (score 2):

I am able to get the container running and loading the azure function by adding an app settings in App Service -> Configuration -> App Settings

`WEBSITES_ENABLE_APP_SERVICE_STORAGE=false`